# Retrieve Authentication Provider Type Using Claimed Identifier

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I've browsed the documentation on **DotNetOpenAuth** and cannot find a method to retrieve the authentication provider type based off of the `ClaimedIdentifier`. I'm looking for a method akin to the following:

```
ProviderType providerType = ClaimedIdentifier.Parse(" .... ").Type;
```

Is there a method to retrieve the Provider Type?

*It'd be great to query DotNetOpenAuth to retrieve this information instead of maintaining a state variable in the application or passing the type as a query string parameter. Though, it is looking like this might be necessary...*

Comment: What is a "provider type"? Such is not a term defined by the OpenID spec.

Comment: What I was going for was a method that would give me a "Provider Name" (i.e. Google, Yahoo, etc...) given a ClaimedIdentifier `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse the Claimed Identifier to try to figure out the provider. While that may work for the common case, there are valid cases where that would fail and you might also be opening yourself for attack.

You acquire the ClaimedIdentifier from an instance of `IAuthenticationRequest`. This interface also has a `Provider` property that returns an `IProviderEndpoint` instance with a `Uri` property on it. This Uri property is how you should recognize Providers that you are particularly interested in. So for example:

```
public void Login(string userSuppliedIdentiifer, OpenIdRelyingParty rp) {
    IAuthenticationRequest request = rp.CreateRequest(userSuppliedIdentifier;
    if (request != null) {
        if (request.Provider.Uri == new Uri("https://www.google.com/o8/ud")) {
            // It's Google!
        } else if (request.Provider.Uri == new Uri("https://me.yahoo.com/whatever-it-is")) {
            // It's Yahoo!
        }

        request.RedirectToProvider();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Right, & thanks for taking the time to create this API! That's the approach I'm currently taking. Though, I was thinking this type of check should be more of a concern for the API and not the client code (managing URI's & the potentiality they could change in the future). If I perform that check in my code there's the possibility the API and my client code will become "out-of-sync." It'd be great if I could call a property/method to retrieve the provider's "friendly name." In the case that a provider's URI changes, all I'd need to do is update to the latest version of DotNetOpenAuth...

Comment: Or, is DotNetOpenAuth completely agnostic of Providers and only responsible for performing OpenAuth requests/responses? In which case, the responsibility of managing provider URI's would be the responsibility of the client?

Comment: Right. DotNetOpenAuth is strictly a protocol library. It doesn't have special strings for any Providers or EPs. But I doubt Google will change their URI, as lots of people do what you're now doing.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but What is "EP"?

Comment: Oops. That was autocorrect for you. EP was supposed to be RP=relying party

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find something similar,something to identify the provider being returned from but so far I have just got around to doing something like this, response.Provider.Uri.ToString().Contains("yahoo"), for yahoo. If there was something better that would be helpful, this seems to cheesy but its the only thing I can work with now.